# I need right syntax of variable

Tags: php, variables

I tried to create this variable:

```
<?php
  echo ${"product['id']"};
?>
```

But it is wrong. Who can help with right syntax?

Comment: maybe i explain not very clear. I need to make complex name of variable. Part of variable will consist of variable too

Comment: echo ${"var1{$varname}"}; example of what i need but in my version is [''] also

Comment: thanks for all who vote - without any solvation. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 echo $product['id'];
?>
```

You don't need to wrap the variable into string if you want to print just one variable. Php will do it for you

If you need to generate variable name in code you can try this:

```
$var1 = 'hello';
$var2 = ' ';
$var3 = 'world';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i) {
    $varName = 'var'.$i;
    print $$varName; // use $$ to use string as a variable name
}
```

Result will be `hello world`

This is the equivalent for previous example

```
$var1 = 'hello';
$var2 = ' ';
$var3 = 'world';

$vars = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach ($vars as $var) {
    $varName = 'var'.$var;
    print $$varName;
}
```

Comment: No. It is not the thing i need. I want to create variable in which name consists of variable too. i mean complex name of variable

Comment: Ok. You can try to work with second technique. I edited the post